# Change proxy settings in Gecko Webbrowser at execution time?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, browser, gecko

I would like to test a list of proxies by loading X page each time with the next proxy in the list.

I'm using a Gecko webbrowser (**GeckoFX**), how I can change the proxy IP:Port at execution time on the webbrowser control to open a webpage using other proxies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
GeckoPreferences.Default["network.proxy.type"] = 1;
GeckoPreferences.Default["network.proxy.http"] = proxyAddress.Host;
GeckoPreferences.Default["network.proxy.http_port"] = proxyAddress.Port;
GeckoPreferences.Default["network.proxy.ssl"] = proxyAddress.Host;
GeckoPreferences.Default["network.proxy.ssl_port"] = proxyAddress.Port;
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for intrude that topic... I test your code: http://pastebin.com/K1RiK10c but whne I press the Button1 nothing happens, the form doesn't charge any page. :/

Comment: @vmas thankyou. PS: do you have idea about how to disable the proxy warning messagebox when the proxy connection fails on the geck webbrowser?

Comment: @ElektroStudios, you can set "browser.xul.error_pages.enabled" to "true" (to display the error page without MessageBox) or you can write your own PromptService to suppress messages.

Answer (score 1):

I've did this helper methods:

```
''' <summary>
''' ProxyTypes of Gecko webbrowser.
''' </summary>
Public Enum ProxyType

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Direct connection, no proxy. 
    ''' (Default in Windows and Mac previous to 1.9.2.4 /Firefox 3.6.4) 
    ''' </summary>
    DirectConnection = 0

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Manual proxy configuration.
    ''' </summary>
    Manual = 1

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Proxy auto-configuration (PAC).
    ''' </summary>
    AutoConfiguration = 2

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Auto-detect proxy settings.
    ''' </summary>
    AutoDetect = 4

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Use system proxy settings. 
    ''' (Default in Linux; default for all platforms, starting in 1.9.2.4 /Firefox 3.6.4)
    ''' </summary>
    System = 5

End Enum

''' <summary>
''' Sets the proxy type of a Gecko Webbrowser.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="ProxyType">Indicates the type of proxy.</param>
Private Sub SetGeckoProxyType(ByVal ProxyType As ProxyType)

    GeckoPreferences.Default("network.proxy.type") = ProxyType

End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Sets the proxy of a Gecko Webbrowser.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Host">Indicates the proxy host.</param>
''' <param name="Port">Indicates the proxy port.</param>
Private Sub SetGeckoProxy(ByVal Host As String,
                          ByVal Port As Integer)

    ' Set the ProxyType to manual configuration.
    GeckoPreferences.Default("network.proxy.type") = ProxyType.Manual

    ' Set the HTP proxy Host and Port.
    GeckoPreferences.Default("network.proxy.http") = Host
    GeckoPreferences.Default("network.proxy.http_port") = Port

    ' Set the SSL proxy Host and Port.
    GeckoPreferences.Default("network.proxy.ssl") = Host
    GeckoPreferences.Default("network.proxy.ssl_port") = Port

End Sub
```